add icons in my matero theme listview header
Here's a revised version of your question for Stack Overflow:
I’m currently working on a project using the Matero theme in Angular, and I've been assigned the task of adding icons to our existing layout. The previous developer implemented the UI using mat-grid instead of mat-tables, and now I need to integrate icons into this structure.
I initially tried to use mat-tables for adding icons, but I found it quite challenging to manage, especially with the existing grid layout. Given that the UI is already built with mat-grid, I’m looking for advice on how to efficiently add icons within this grid system.
Here are my specific questions:
What is the best way to integrate icons (such as Angular Material icons or FontAwesome) within mat-grid tiles?
How can I ensure that the icons are responsive and maintain a consistent appearance across different screen sizes?
Are there any best practices or patterns I should follow when adding icons to a mat-grid layout, especially compared to mat-tables?
I’d appreciate any suggestions, code snippets, or resources that could help me achieve this efficiently. Thanks in advance!
